# For any integer n⩾1, how do you show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^k}{\sqrt{k+0.5}}\leqslant2^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}-\frac{4n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}$

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math

For any integer $n\geqslant1$, how do you show that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^k}{\sqrt{k+0.5}}\leqslant2^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}-\frac{4n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}$$

Do you need to find the formula of the partial sum of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^k}{\sqrt{k+0.5}}$ first before moving on to proof whether the inequality is true?

I could not find a suitable way of writing the formula of the partial sum, since this is a divergent series, or is there a way to do so?

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: Have you tried integral comparison ?

Comment: Actually, this is supposed to be a high school contest math question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following upper bound

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{\sqrt{k+1/2}} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n 2^k \leq 2^{n+1}.$$

This hints that the required inequality holds for sufficiently large $n$. We now show that it holds for all $n\geq 1$, i.e., for all $n\geq 1$
$$2^{n+1}\leq 2^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}-4n^{1.5}/3.$$

First observe this holds for $n=1$. Then the claim follows since for all $n\geq 2$
$$\sqrt{n}\leq 2\cdot (\sqrt{n+1}-1) \quad \text{and}\quad 4\cdot n \leq 3\cdot 2^{n}.$$

The following manipulations prove the claim
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}&\leq 2\cdot (\sqrt{n+1}-1)\\
2^{n}\sqrt{n}&\leq 2^{n+1}\cdot (\sqrt{n+1}-1)\\
4n^{1.5}/3&\leq 2^{n+1}\cdot (\sqrt{n+1}-1)\\
2^{n+1}&\leq 2^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}-4n^{1.5}/3.
\end{align}